# sample path mismatching in AOT sample

Tags: json, angular, angular2-aot

I am trying to create Angular 2 sample ngc and JIT compiler. With JIT compiler i can run the sample but with ngc compiler am  facing issue with component.html file path.

> npm run ngc
>
> ejangular2-systemjs-starter@1.0.0 ngc E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT
>   "node" copy-dist-files.js && rollup -c rollup-config.js && ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
>   Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: E:/AOT/seed-application-changes/sample-AOT/src/src/app.
>   component.html
>       at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT\node_modules\@a
>   ngular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:291:19)
>       at CompilerHost.loadResource (E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT\node_modules\@angular\compiler
>   -cli\src\compiler_host.js:230:85)
>       at Object.get (E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compil
>   er.umd.js:26365:111)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT\node_modules\@angular\compile
>   r\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13744:47)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (E:\AOT\seed-application-changes\sample-AOT\node_modules\
>   @angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13790:25)

Below are my configuration.

[sample structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRENm.png)

**rollup.config.js**

```
 import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
 import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
 import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
entry: 'src/main.js',
dest: 'aot/build.js', // output a single application bundle
sourceMap: false,
format: 'iife',
onwarn: function(warning) {
// Skip certain warnings

// should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }
// intercepts in some rollup versions
if ( warning.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1    ) { return; }

// console.warn everything else
console.warn( warning.message );
  },
plugins: [
  nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
  commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
  }),
  uglify()
 ]
}
```

**tsconfig-aot.json**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
 },

 "files": [
"src/app.module.ts",
"src/main-aot.ts"
 ],

 "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
   }
   }
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"ngc": "\"node\" copy-dist-files.js && rollup -c rollup-config.js && ngc -p   tsconfig-aot.json",
"serve": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json"
},
```

Comment: did you copy the HTML files to the folder where you're compiling the source files with ngc?